# Looking for a 70s/80s YA Fantasy Quest Novel with a Reluctant Heroine in a Celtic-like Culture

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I don't remember a lot about the plot -- the cover was yellow and featured an illustrated brunette heroine in medieval or earlier clothing.

I think that it's a matriarchy and that the king has either been sent away or has disappeared.  I think there was some sort of prophesy that he could not father the heir to the throne, so it was necessary for him to leave.

Also, I think it starts with some sort of annual festival where a handsome foreigner appears and the princess heroine makes eyes at him until her mother claims him as her consort in one of those year-and-a-day things.

Then, after the queen has delivered an heir, the princess and the now ex-consort are sent on a quest of some sort, maybe to search for the missing king????

I remember thinking at the time that I read it that it was really different from anything I'd read before, but I don't think I'd had enough knowledge of other cultures like the ancient Celtics and their less restrictive views on sex and marriage or matriarchal societies to appreciate what I was reading.  Now that I'm older, more well-read, and far more open-minded, I'd like to reread it...if only I could remember it...

Comment: It doesn't ring any bells, but then the description is rather general. If you could remember any details like character, tribe or place names that might help.

Comment: I keep thinking that heroine has an Rh-name like Rhian or Rhiannon or Rhea or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe 'Starsilk' by Sydney Van Syoc. It's book 3 of a trilogy, the others are 'Darkchild' and 'Bluesong'.
The heroine's name is Reyna.

Comment: Yes!  You found it!  Though how you got that from my description. :)  I had no idea it was part of a series.  I've ordered a used copy of a collection of all three.  Thank you so much!!!!!!